# how i can show a record from db after comparing with an id from href

Tags: django

the problem is im  not able to  show record in  edit_vendor.html  after comparing  id from  href
plz giude someone 
i have views.py like

```
def vendor(request,id):
    key = request.GET.get('id')
    obj = Vendor.objects.get(id = key)
    return  render_to_response('edit_vendor.html',{'obj': obj},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template

```
<a href ='/vendor/{{vendor.id}}/'> edit </a>
```

edit_vendor.html

```
{% for Vendor in obj %}
<tr>
<form action="/update/" method="get">
   Vendor Name:<input type ='text' name= 'name' value ={{Vendor.name}}></br>
   Address: <input type ='text' name= 'address' value =  {{Vendor.address}}></br>
   Contact:<input  type = 'text' name= 'contact' value =  {{Vendor.contact}}></br>
   Created Date <input  type ='text' name='date' value = {{Vendor.created_date}}></br>
                <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='update' />
</form>
</tr>
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: try `obj = Vendor.objects.get(id=id)` instead of the current `obj = Vendor.objects.get(id = key)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `get()` which returns always returns a single object, and not a list.

But let's back up and fix your view.

1. If you're expecting to only ever get 1 object for a query, use the get_object_or_404 shortcut. This is handy, as it will automatically get and trap the case where someone tries to fetch a Vendor ID that doesn't exist.

So your view should look like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404

def vendor(request, id):
    vendor = get_object_or_404(Vendor, id=id)
    return  render_to_response('edit_vendor.html', {'vendor': vendor}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The next thing is keep in mind that `get` ORM calls return a single object, not a list. So this:

```
{% for Vendor in obj %}
```

… is wrong.

You probably just want do do:

```
<tr>
    <form action="/update/" method="get">
        Vendor Name:<input type ='text' name= 'name' value ={{vendor.name}}></br>
        Address: <input type ='text' name= 'address' value =  {{vendor.address}}></br>
        Contact:<input  type = 'text' name= 'contact' value =  {{vendor.contact}}></br>
        Created Date <input  type ='text' name='date' value = {{vendor.created_date}}></br>
        <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='update' />
    </form>
</tr>
```